# "Error: Unresolved compilation problems" with Wowza module

Tags: java, opencv, wowza

I've developed a module for Wowza in Java that uses OpenCV. Everything worked fine on my development PC because Eclipse took care of correctly linking the OpenCV library.

Now I have to run this jar on my server and I've only got the command line.
I've managed to build a jar but when I run it I get this error from Wowza:

```
Exception in thread "ServerHandler.69" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
        The import org.opencv cannot be resolved
        The import org.opencv cannot be resolved
        Mat cannot be resolved to a type
```

How can I get Wowza to run my module linked with an external jar?  Can I link this jar to its native implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your module has compile time dependent jar files, you need to do one of these things:

- copy those jar files into the `lib` directory of your Wowza installation
- build a so called fat jar file, which basically means that you pour the class files from the dependent libraries into a single jar file

The first approach is easier on build side, you can use the original `build.xml` that you get in the Wowza IDE. The drawback is that you need to give all the jar files to your customers. The second approach means customized build but easier distribution.